# Determine if an array of Dates includes a certain date by condition in Pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, date, pyspark

I have an array column containing dates.  I want to return a true false column that searches the array and determines if the array contains a date prior to a certain condition.

Example:

| Date_Array | Location | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [4/22/21,3/21/21] | Dallas | 5 |
| [5/22/21,6/18/21] | Dallas | 5 |

If my condition is any date prior to 4/01/21, the result should be this:

| Date_Array | Location | ID | bool_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [4/22/21,3/21/21] | Dallas | 5 | TRUE |
| [5/22/21,6/18/21] | Dallas | 5 | FALSE |

Can this be done with Pyspark or Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your actual condition, you can customize the code here, but overall idea is getting the max and min date of the array and use that for any comparison

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('max_date', F.array_max('date_array'))
    .withColumn('min_date', F.array_min('date_array'))
    .withColumn('bool_date1', (F.col('min_date') < F.lit(datetime.fromisoformat('2021-04-01'))))
    .show()
)

+------------------------+--------+---+----------+----------+----------+
|date_array              |location|id |max_date  |min_date  |bool_date1|
+------------------------+--------+---+----------+----------+----------+
|[2021-04-22, 2021-03-21]|Dallas  |5  |2021-04-22|2021-03-21|true      |
|[2021-05-22, 2021-06-18]|Dallas  |5  |2021-06-18|2021-05-22|false     |
+------------------------+--------+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.